# Spark cache behaviour when the source table is modified

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have a hive table("person"), which is cached in Spark.

```
sqlContext.sql("create table person (name string, age int)") //Create a new table
//Add some values to the table
...
...
//Cache the table in Spark
sqlContext.cacheTable("person") 
sqlContext.isCached("person") //Returns true
sqlContext.sql("insert into table person values ("Foo", 25)") // Insert some other value in the table

//Check caching status again
sqlContext.isCached("person") //Returns true
```

sqlContext is **HiveContext**.

Will the entries inserted after **cacheTable("person")** statement be cached?
In other words, ("Foo", 25) entry is cached in Spark or not?

If not, how can I cache only the entries inserted later?
I don't want to first uncache and then again cache the whole table.